# A text field is being added to the facet

Tags: search

I have a text field,whose value when filled,is added to the facet (using Search api and facet api).How can I prevent it from not being added to the facet?I want to index it but not being added to the facet.
Thanks

Comment: So you want the field to be indexed (so it's available for keyword searches), but not to act like a facet for facet-based searches? Have you enabled the field as a facet on the "facet" tab when editing the Search API index?

Comment: Yeah you are corret,the field was enabled as a facet.It was done by default to the disto I am using.Thank you for the help!